# Create a BigQuery Table everyday from a CSV file stored in Cloud Storage

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

On GCP I have a new csv added everyday at 2 am in a Cloud Storage folder (format is something like mydata_yyyymmdd.csv).

I am trying to **schedule** an upload of this file at 2:30 am everyday in a Big Query Table.

I succeeded in creating a dataflow that constantly screen my Cloud Storage folder and constantly update my BigQuery table if a new file is added but I don't find this optimal as :

- my dataflow is running all day long while I only need to run it once a day (increasing costs)
- this solution doesn't create a new Big Query table everyday, it just appends all csv to my Big Query table

Can you help me with the tools I should use in GCP to achieve this ?

Thanks a lot for your help, it is very much appreciated

Comment: My immediate gut reaction is to use Cloud Functions (see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage).  The Cloud Function would be a fragment of logic that you provide.  The Cloud Function would be automatically triggered when the CSV file is added.  The logic in the Cloud Function would then read the data from Cloud Storage and create the corresponding BQ table.  Since there is no charge for a Cloud Function that doesn't run, no obvious wastage.  It also handles delays when the CSV hasn't arrived in time.

Comment: Can you share what you do to improve your code to achieve what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I can help with the "Solution that creates a new Big Query table periodically". I have a file called `predictions_1514.csv` in a google cloud location (*an output prediction file that gets dumped weekly in the same cloud storage location - I basically delete the old one, and then replace it with the new file but of the same name*). And then I needed to import the `.csv` content into a Big query table. For achieving this, I am using Jupyter Notebook, which I trigger to run using CRON. My solution was based on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv). Code is below:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
# table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("post_abbr", "STRING"),
    ],
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    # The source format defaults to CSV, so the line below is optional.
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
)
uri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/us-states/us-states.csv"

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
)  # Make an API request.

load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```